# How to create a difference column based on conditions?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe and need to add a new column that shows difference. So `CurrentDay - PreviousDay` for each sample. For instance for R1 15-13.2 = 1.8 would be result for new column. See sample data and answers below.

This is a sample dataset

```
Date,color,Sample,Height
10/24/2021,red,R1,13.2
10/24/2021,red,R2,0
10/24/2021,red,R3,9
10/24/2021,red,R4,16
10/24/2021,red,R5,4
10/24/2021,red,R6,15
10/24/2021,red,R7,9
10/24/2021,red,R8,16.5
10/24/2021,orange,O1,12.5
10/24/2021,orange,O2,17.5
10/24/2021,orange,O3,16
10/24/2021,orange,O4,12.9
10/24/2021,orange,O5,.1
10/24/2021,orange,O6,3.5
10/24/2021,orange,O7,8.5
10/24/2021,orange,O8,0
10/24/2021,yellow,Y1,0
10/24/2021,yellow,Y2,8.5
10/24/2021,yellow,Y3,11
10/24/2021,yellow,Y4,16.5
10/24/2021,yellow,Y5,14.5
10/24/2021,yellow,Y6,15
10/24/2021,yellow,Y7,5.9
10/24/2021,yellow,Y8,13
10/25/2021,red,R1,15
10/25/2021,red,R2,0
10/25/2021,red,R3,15
10/25/2021,red,R4,17.5
10/25/2021,red,R5,4.5
10/25/2021,red,R6,18
10/25/2021,red,R7,9
10/25/2021,red,R8,18
10/25/2021,orange,O1,16
10/25/2021,orange,O2,19.9
10/25/2021,orange,O3,17.8
10/25/2021,orange,O4,16
10/25/2021,orange,O5,.1
10/25/2021,orange,O6,6.5
10/25/2021,orange,O7,13
10/25/2021,orange,O8,0
10/25/2021,yellow,Y1,0
10/25/2021,yellow,Y2,10.9
10/25/2021,yellow,Y3,12
10/25/2021,yellow,Y4,18
10/25/2021,yellow,Y5,16.5
10/25/2021,yellow,Y6,16
10/25/2021,yellow,Y7,8
10/25/2021,yellow,Y8,14.6
```

The answers for the appended column should look like this

```
R1  = 1.8
R2  = 0  
R3  = 6  
R4  = 1.5
R5  = .5
R6  = 3 
R7  = 0 
R8  = 1.5
O1  = 3.5
O2  = 2.4
O3  = 1.8 
O4  = 3.1 
O5  = 0  
O6  = 3  
O7  = 4.5
08  = 0
Y1  = 0
Y2  = 2.4
Y3  = 1
Y4  = 1.5
Y5  = 2
Y6  = 1
Y7  = 2.1
Y8  = 1.6
```

Comment: Are you limited to `python`'s standard library or are you allowed to use external modules like `numpy` or `pandas`?

Comment: yes we can use numpy and or pandas is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `diff`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
difference = df.groupby('Sample').Height.diff()
mask = ~difference.isnull()
print(pd.concat([df[mask].Sample, difference[mask]], 1))
```

---

```
   Sample  Height
24     R1     1.8
25     R2     0.0
26     R3     6.0
27     R4     1.5
28     R5     0.5
29     R6     3.0
30     R7     0.0
31     R8     1.5
32     O1     3.5
33     O2     2.4
34     O3     1.8
35     O4     3.1
36     O5     0.0
37     O6     3.0
38     O7     4.5
39     O8     0.0
40     Y1     0.0
41     Y2     2.4
42     Y3     1.0
43     Y4     1.5
44     Y5     2.0
45     Y6     1.0
46     Y7     2.1
47     Y8     1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The final `for` loop will print the output in the exact format you want:

```
df = df.assign(difference = df.groupby("Sample")[["Height"]].diff())

df = df[~df['difference'].isnull()]

for _, line in df.iterrows():
    print("{:<4}= {:>3s}".format(line["Sample"], str(round(line["difference"] * 100)/100)))
```